# Cauchy product of two different series

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

How to build the Cauchy product of the two series : $$
\exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$ and $$
\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$. Thank you  for your help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you have $u = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ and $v = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$ then the Cauchy Product $u.v$ is given by $p = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{n}$ where $c_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{j}b_{n-j}$. How to do this in the case of $\exp(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ as given previously.

Comment: @Tahar Please avoid double dollar signs in comments unless really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: The Cauchy product of the two series is simply the Taylor series of $e^x\sin x$.

Since $e^x\sin x = \text{Im}[e^xe^{ix}] = \text{Im}[e^{(1+i)x}]$, you can simply compute the Taylor series of $e^{(1+i)x}$ and take the imaginary part. This will be the same as the series for $e^x$, except $x$ is replaced by $(1+i)x$.

Using DeMoivre's Formula, $(1+i)^n = (\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4})^n = 2^{n/2}e^{in\pi/4}$

Comment: Thank you for your help. The goal of this exercice is to do much more complicated product of series. I do have to compute the following indefinite integral : $$I = \int \frac{\exp(-b^2x^2)erf(ax)}{x^2}dx$$ direct integration is impossible in this case. But by the series developement there is a chance at leat to find an approximation of this integral. Hope it helps. Many thanks.